# Proving a solution exists to an integral equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I have the following problem involving an integral equation:

> Let $ g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. We are asked to show that there exists a continuous function $ f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} $ satisfying:
>
> $$ f(x) - \int_{0}^{x} f(x-t)e^{-t^2}dt = g(x) $$

I realize the integral is a convolution so I was thinking about using Laplace transforms but the functions have a limited domain of support. Any help is appreciated here thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $T: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ by

$$(Tf)(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(x-t)e^{-t^2}dt + g(x).$$

Then show that

$$||Tf-Th||_{_\infty} \le \frac{4}{5}||f-h||_{_\infty}.$$

Proceed with Banach's fixed point theorem.

Comment: To get a slightly better constant, use $e^{-t^2}=\frac{1}{1+t^2+\frac12t^4+\frac16t^6+..}\le\frac1{1+t^2}$ so that $$\int_0^1e^{-t^2}dt\le\arctan(1)=\frac\pi4.$$

Answer (score 1):

A constructive proof:

$$f(x) - \int_{0}^{x} f(x-t)e^{-t^2}dt = g(x)$$

Let's substitute:

$$t=x-w$$

$$f(x) - \int_{0}^x f(w)e^{-(x-w)^2}dw = g(x)$$

This is now a Volterra integral equation of the second kind and the existence of the solution can be proven by the standard theorems for such equations (namely, an iterative procedure).

---

Another constructive method would be to use Fourier series on $[0,1]$:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n  e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty B_n  e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

The series exist and converge for any continuous functions. $B_n$ are found by the usual method from the known $g(x)$.

Substitution gives us:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n  \left(e^{2 \pi i n x} - \int_{0}^x e^{2 \pi i n w} e^{-(x-w)^2}dw \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty B_n  e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n e^{2 \pi i n x}  \left(1 - \int_{0}^x e^{-2 \pi i n t} e^{-t^2}dt \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty B_n  e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

Integrating gives us:

$$\int_{0}^x e^{-2 \pi i n t} e^{-t^2}dt=- i \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{- \pi^2 n^2} (\operatorname{erfi} (\pi n)-\operatorname{erfi} (\pi n-ix) ) $$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A_n e^{2 \pi i n x}  \left(1 +  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{- \pi^2 n^2} (\operatorname{erfi} (\pi n)-\operatorname{erfi} (\pi n-ix) ) \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty B_n  e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

Multiply by $e^{-2 \pi i m x} $ and integrate:

$$A_m  \left(1 +  \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{- \pi^2 m^2} \operatorname{erfi} (\pi m) \right)-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty A _n e^{- \pi^2 n^2}  \int_0^1 e^{2 \pi i (n-m) x} \operatorname{erfi} (\pi n-ix) dx  = B_m $$

All the integral exist and so we obtained a system of linear equation for $A_n$. Note that by looking at the explicit terms and the asymptotic expansion of the imaginary error function we can easily prove the the series converges.

To actually find them and thus find $f(x)$ we can consider a sequence of approximations:

$$f_N(x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N A^{(N)}_n  e^{2 \pi i n x}$$

For each finite $N$ we can solve the system of equations and find $A^{(N)}_n$.

$$f(x)= \lim_{N \to \infty} f_N(x)$$

Thus we have constructed $f(x)$ and proved that it exists. All the necessary theorems for Fourier series are proven in various literature.